# How to dynamically change setTimeout (AOP) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

My goal is to:

1. Use aspect oriented programming (AOP) to change setTimeout in any production codes from an SDK so:

   - setTimeout can be executed immediately, this can probably be achieved through getting the callback from the setTimeout's argument[0], and clear setTimeout once the event fires and run the argument[0].
   - delay setTimeout, this can probably be achieved through getting the callback from the setTimeout's argument[0], and clear setTimeout once the event fires and start a new setTimeout with argument[0].
2. Capable of being injected through async method.

The goal 2 is where the problem is. Since it is possible the production script could potentially run before the SDK is injected, the setTimeout used before the SDK rewrites the method, will escape the wrap.

The question is, what would be your solution to achieve the above two goals.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: @gforce301 The question is, what would be your solution to achieve the above two goals.

Comment: your solution is as far away from AOP as can be. You just want to modify a global method depending on the environment it is supposed to run in. Make this modified `setTimeout` part of your production code that your are hopefully in control of.